# React - how to filter items in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time encountering this so please bear with me.

I'm writing a React web app that pulls in data from a local db.json file and stores it in global state using the Context API. I have the data displayed on the page and I have a dropdown that pulls in the category names of this data as well.

When I select a dropdown item from the list, I'd like it to filter the list of data to that selected category.

Currently when you select a dropdown item, I get the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined".

This tells me that I'm probably not accessing the 'category' data properly.

Here's an example of the JSON, I want to access the 'category':

```
{
    "machines": [{
            "category": "Skid Steer and Compact Track Loaders",
            // ^^^ I want to access this
            "product_details": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "model": "226D3",
                    "power": "67.1",
                    "rated_operating_capacity": "1550",
                    "operating_weight": "5849",
                    "description": "Built for tough work, the Caterpillar® Skid Steer Loaders incorporate big iron features. These machines deliver Cat reliability, durability, and efficient operation, even in the toughest working conditions.",
                    "image": "https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Caterpillar/CM20190910-c686b-0fdbf"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's the code for filtering the dropdown items:

```
// Load in global state
const { data, isLoading } = useAPI();

const [categories, setCategories] = useState("");

// DROPDOWN - filter based on category
const filterCategory = (e, category) => {
    setCategories(e.target.value);
    return category.toLowerCase().indexOf(categories.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    // ^^^ this is where it throws the error
  };
```

Here's the code that renders out the list:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-3">
          {/* Dropdown */}
          <div className="options">
            {!isLoading ? (
              <>
                <select
                  value={categories}
                  onChange={filterCategory}
                  className="product-dropdown"
                  name="product-dropdown"
                >
                  {data.map((item) => (
                    <option value={item.category}>{item.category}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </>
            ) : (
              <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* List of machines */}
      {!isLoading ? (
        <MachineList
          filterProducts={filterProducts}
          filterCategory={filterCategory}
        />
      ) : (
        "Loading..."
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Is there a way I can access the 'category' and make it so when I choose an option from the dropdown, the page filters and only shows those items belonging to a specific category?

Comment: A couple of issues with the code. 1. [`onChange`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) on select tag takes only one parameter. So, the category parameter of your `filterCategory` is ALWAYS undefined. 2. To extract category you should use `e.target.value`, 3. It us useless to return anything to `onChange` function, it does not expect anything to be returned, 4. it is confusing to call a singular variable, plural. In your case, you may rename `category` as `selectedCategory` and `categories` should be named `category`, but that's just me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState('')
const filteredProducts = data.filter(machine => machine.category.toLowerCase() === selectedCategory.toLowerCase())
```

<-->

```
<select
   value={selectedCategory}
   onChange={(e) => setSelectedCategory(e.target.value}
   className="product-dropdown"
   name="product-dropdown"
 >

 <MachineList
      filterProducts={filteredProducts}
 />
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, implemented your code - here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/79boc?file=/src/components/SearchFilter.js

I don't get an error upon selecting anymore, however the list doesn't filter. Any idea?

Comment: In MachineList.js, you need to use "filteredCategories.map((item) =>" instead of data

Comment: Implemented the change and getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Your prop names don't match. You need filteredCategories={filteredCategories} for  <MachineList>...</MachineList> in SearchFilter.js